# What is a natural French construction for "How can you be ... ?"

Tags: constructions

In conversation, I said incredulously and jokingly:

> Comment peux-tu être trois ans plus jeune que moi et pourtant **si mature** ?

This phrasing sprang to mind in the flow of conversation, but now I think back on it, I wonder if it might have been better to place the part "si mature" first, given that this is the surprising bit that should be directly and immediately emphasised by "Comment peux-tu":

> Comment peux-tu être **si mature** alors que tu es trois ans plus jeune que moi ?
>
> or: Comment se fait-il que tu sois **si mature** alors que tu es trois ans plus jeune que moi ?

Comment: *Mature* is definitely an anglicism. The right translation is *mûr*.

Comment: @jlliagre merci encore une fois de me rendre un peu moins bête... c'est aussi pour cela que j'adore ce site, on y apprend plein de choses même sans poser de questions...

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give an objective answer to this question. All sentences sound good and equivalent to my ears (aside from the *pouvoir*/*se faire* distinctions).

I would probably tend to put the fact I learned last (what you call the surprising bit) first in the sentence, unless I want to make it sound like a deeper thought.

Comment: Incidentally, in the second version, would you use other conjunctions than "alors que"?

Comment: No, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

L'emplacement de mature dans la phrase n'a pas trop d'importance, les deux fonctionnent. On pourra dire :

> Comment peux-tu avoir trois ans de moins que moi et être aussi mature ?
>
> Comment peux-tu être aussi mature et avoir trois ans de moins que moi ?

Plusieurs choses :

- pour indiquer l'âge, on peut utiliser le verbe 'avoir' et dans ce cas, on écrira

  > Comment peux-tu avoir trois ans de moins que moi, et être aussi mature ?
- il est possible d'utiliser le verbe 'être', mais la phrase est plus pompeuse :

  > Comment peux-tu être, de trois ans, plus jeune que moi, et être si mature ?
- une phrase équivalente et quand même moins pompeuse :

  > Comment peux-tu être plus jeune que moi de trois ans et être si mature ?
- Enfin, il est tout à fait possible d'utiliser le mot mature. Quelqu'un qui agit comme un enfant est dit 'immature'. Ou ironiquement, on dira "c'est mature, ça, tiens !". En tant que jeune français, mûr et mature ont pour moi une légère nuance. Mûr qualifie quelqu'un d'âgé et de sage, mature qualifie plutôt quelqu'un qui est adulte et qui s'occupe de ses responsabilités. Ainsi, on parlera d'un comportement mature et pas d'un comportement mûr.

Comment: Il « faut » utiliser « avoir » ? C'est pas comme si les occurrences manquaient, [même dans la littérature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ans+plus+jeune+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3). En revanche, entièrement d'accord avec le paragraphe sur « mature », et je ne suis pas si jeune que ça. Mais au final, tout ça ce n'est pas vraiment le sujet.

Comment: Effectivement, on est pas obligé d'utiliser avoir comme j'en mentionne l'option sur mon deuxième item. Je corrige ça. Merci !

Answer (score -1):

The last two constructions are better because they are more natural and that is so on the count that it is more logical to wonder about the unusual maturity than the age, which after all is known ; to doubt the age of someone is proper when there is an incertitude or when the age appears to be incredible. In the present case and such other cases, doing that is awkward; at least, it seems so to me. The surprising bit, as you say,  should be the focus of your enonciation (at least in the present sentence).

By the way, « mature » has been an English word until recently; it is not yet in the TLFi, not in the Ac., not in the Littré but it is found in the on line Larousse;  a periphrase can be used to replace it, though.

- Comment peux-tu avoir tant de maturité alors que tu es trois ans plus jeune que moi ?

There is another problem; maturity is not considered as a quality that depends on age according  to a proportionality factor that should be the same for everyone; moreover in the French culture, maturity is not something that is developed in a human being all his/her life so as to be for ever growing until death; wisdom may be considered such a caracteristic or certain skills; in the French culture it is considered that full maturity is reached once and for all at a point between youth and old age and that it remains constant for the rest of adulthood, a period from which is excluded very old age. On top of that, a mere 3 year difference is not a factor worth considering; here is the definition of the « age of maturity » or, elliptically of « maturité » ;

> (TLFi) Âge de maturité; p. ell., la maturité. Période de la vie comprise entre la jeunesse et la vieillesse pendant laquelle les facultés humaines ont atteint leur ultime développement.

I believe that the idea is not expressed in the proper terms. Maybe it is preferable to consider a quality such as wisdom and not to make it so dependent on age.

Comment: @user17522 The word is not found in any of the great dictionaries nor in a translation dictionary; however, it is true that it has been introduced in the language some time ago recently : it appears in the Larousse and a translation dictionary, but I don't use them, so the error, otherwiseI would have mentioned that. If you can talk of this caracteristic in various degrees (using "si" elicits that), evidently you can say "more or less mature" ("a more mature person" is common in English) and then "beaucoup de maturité" (much maturity" is used in English). (champ 1)

Comment: @user17522 *Mature* is being used in recent French but is definitely an anglicism and rarely found in written material. *Immature* is an anglicism too but less controversial, probably because we already have *mûr* for mature but no antonym for it (we use *pas mûr*).

Comment: @user17522 I do see the point of applying logic to a joke : a joke isn't a joke because you've allowed yourself to say a lot of nonsense in it but because on the contrary it makes a lot of sense and that it departs from that whole lot of sense in only one subtle part where a trick causes the usual logic to yield funny ideas.

Comment: Pour le TLF note : « la rédaction du TLF est terminée depuis 1994 et la plupart des contributeurs ont quitté le laboratoire. Il n’a pas vocation à être mis à jour. Cette ressource, qui ne fait pas l’objet d’une veille lexicographique, est donc close « en l’état ». Il est donc tout à fait naturel que les définitions qui s’y trouvent ne rendent pas compte des évolutions de la société. ». Pour le Littré note que : « Il s'agit d'un dictionnaire ancien, paru à la fin du XIXe siècle. Ses vedettes comme ses définitions s'appliquent à une langue française qui a beaucoup évolué en près de 150 ans. ».

Comment: Note aussi que la rédaction de _Ac.9_ entreprise en 1986 n'est pas encore [terminée](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/presentation.html) et que _Ac.8_ c'est 1932-1935. C'est la raison pour laquelle tu devrais à mon avis consulter le plus grand nombre de dictionnaires possible et pas te contenter uniquement de _TLF/Ac/Littré_ dont le contenu peut s'avérer incomplet vu leur nature/état...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Oui, s'appuyer les yeux fermés sur le TLFi n'est pas une démarche trés sécure... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Il vaut mieux ne pas mettre tous ses yeux dans le même panier, ni même dans presque tous les [paniers](http://www.pierrebouillon.com/2009/11/un-tiens-vaut-mieux-ou-un-tien-vaut.html) !

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Le *mature* anglais est bien sûr d'origine française, mais en français, ce mot savant a cessé d'être utilisé au profit de son doublon populaire *mûr* sauf dans quelques usages spécialisés (abcès mature, poisson mature) et peut-être au Québec. Son utilisation au XXIe siècle pour qualifier la maturité d'une personne procède donc en France de l'anglicisme, ce sens de *mature* n'étant attesté en français qu'entre le XIIIe et le XVe siècle. N'ayant pas de pendant non savant, maturité, maturation, immature etc. font eux partie du lexique français moderne.

Comment: @jlliagre C'était bien à moi que tu adressais le commentaire (bien intéressant par ailleurs) ? Mon propos sur le panier visait l'emploi des dictionnaires et c'est moi qui a fait +1 sur le commentaire sous la question. À l'oral j'entends ça aisément au Québec et j'ai trouvé étrange que la BDL n'en traite pas dans un article comme [celui-ci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4670) ni ailleurs et ça me laisse croire que l'anglicisme serait de plus en plus accepté ici ou qu'on n'est pas assez certain pour se prononcer. Ça devrait faire l'objet d'une question sur le site...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Oui, c'était bien à toi. Je n'était pas très [sécure](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=secure&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=2619) de comprendre de ton opinion sur l'opportunité d'utiliser mature...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Il fallait bien sûr lire *...de comprendre ton opinion...*

Answer (score -1):

I think three changes are necessary: one to change **être trois ans** to **avoir trois ans**, the second to change the last phrase to a *whereas* clause, and the third to use **mûr / mûre** instead of **mature**. Hence:

> Comment peux-tu avoir trois ans plus jeune que moi, tandis que tu es si
>   mûr[e] ?

Comment: The phrasing you chose requires further changes imho: _Comment peux-tu avoir trois ans de moins que moi et être si mûr[e] ?_ I would add _que ça_ at the end, but that's just me...

Comment: @Survenant9r7: Quite right.